# Move button randomly with click inside perimeter of an imageview

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, imagebutton

Basically here is what I want to do. I want an ImageButton that randomly changes position once clicked, but the button must stay within the ImageView I have on the screen. So far I have the button moving randomly but am not sure how to limit its movement to only be inside of the ImageView's boundaries. Please help if you can, I have also attached my current Java code.

JAVA CODE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageButton startbutton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final ImageView buttonfield = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    startbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {


        Random r = new Random();
        int buttonHeight;
        int buttonWidth;
        buttonHeight = startbutton.getHeight();
        buttonWidth = startbutton.getWidth();
        int xLeft = r.nextInt(480 + buttonHeight);
        int yUp = r.nextInt(900 + buttonWidth);
        int xRight = r.nextInt(480 + buttonHeight);
        int yDown = r.nextInt(900 + buttonWidth);

        startbutton.setX(xLeft);       
        startbutton.setY(yUp);
        startbutton.setX(xRight);
        startbutton.setY(yDown);
        }





    });
    }
}
```